# Click Event not binding?

Tags: jquery, css, click, live

I have a menu, I'm trying to change the background image of a div elsewhere in the html to the href of the link clicked. It's odd because i have a script that does almost the same thing, on mouseover. I tried to tweak it to work for this, but to no avail.

```
    $(".IG_Nav_List a").live('click',function(){ 
        var src = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.Background').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')'); 
    });

    ////////////////

   <div class="Background"></div>

    <ul class="IG_Nav_List">
       <li><a href="Surface/A.jpg" onclick="return false;">AAAA</a></li>
       <li><a href="Surface/B.jpg" onclick="return false;">BBBB</a></li>
       <li><a href="Surface/C.jpg" onclick="return false;">CCCC</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for starters:

```
'url(+src+)'
```

should probably be

```
'url('+src+')'
```

Comment: just pipped me to the post ;)

Comment: Right, i figured that'd be a part of the problem. However, this doesn't fix it.

Comment: Your script works now. I have tested in chrome and ie. Make sure that your div exists. I had to give the div a height and width to see the background change. Also, make sure your image path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the element with the `Background` class but..

Here's a catch:

```
$('.Background').css('background-image', 'url(+src+)');
```

should be

```
$('.Background').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your code, look at this line:

```
$('.Background').css('background-image', 'url(+src+)');
```

This should be

```
$('.Background').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
```